# converting a mySQL Trigger, to TSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql

Looking for help converting this mySQL Trigger, to TSQL.

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF not exists TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE_ADD_POSITION 
AFTER INSERT ON TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.WATCHLIST_POSITION IS NULL
BEGIN 
    UPDATE TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE SET
    WATCHLIST_POSITION = (SELECT COUNT(*) - 1 FROM TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE WHERE WATCHLIST_USER = NEW.WATCHLIST_USER)
    WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
END;
```

Comment: try this :`CREATE TRIGGER TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE_ADD_POSITION 
AFTER INSERT ON TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE
BEGIN 
    UPDATE TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE 
SET
    WATCHLIST_POSITION = (SELECT COUNT(*) - 1 FROM TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE WHERE WATCHLIST_USER = inserted.WATCHLIST_USER)
    WHERE rowid = inserted.rowid and inserted.WATCHLIST_POSITION is null`

Comment: Thanks... But my Management Studio does not accept the syntax.

it gets better if i rewrite it like this:
CREATE TRIGGER TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE_ADD_POSITION ON TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE AFTER INSERT ON TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE BEGIN  UPDATE TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE SET WATCHLIST_POSITION = (SELECT COUNT(*) - 1 FROM TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE WHERE WATCHLIST_USER = inserted.WATCHLIST_USER) WHERE rowid = inserted.rowid and inserted.WATCHLIST_POSITION is null

But then it expects a "AS, NOT_FOR, With"

Comment: are you using ssms?

Comment: i'm using Microsoft SQL server Management studio (2014)

Comment: @SimonBruun what is this trigger supposed to do? There may be a *function* that does that already without requiring triggers. MySQL has no windowing, analytic or ranking functions. SQL Server has a *lot* - `ROW_NUMBER(), RANK(), LAG(),LEAD()`, which can be applied to all of the data or parts of it. Looks like you only need a ranking function?

Comment: @SimonBruun what is the *table* schema? Which is the primary key?

Comment: Thanks.. I'm sorry but I only got the above MySQL from my software supplier, and they have told me that it needed to be converted to whatever language we are using, which is TSQL.. So I actually don't know what the trigger is supposed to do, other then the provided msSQL script. If you think some of these analytic or ranking functions could be used, could you please show me an example ?

Comment: I already posted my guesses as an answer. What are the *results* supposed to look like? What is the table schema? Any indexes on the table that use `WATCHLIST_POSITION` ?

Comment: Wow.. the help on this site, is overwhelming !
thanks for all your effort to make this work for me.

Please give me some time to take it all in..

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your help

I ended up with this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE_ADD_POSITION 
ON TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;
DECLARE @MyField_USER varchar(250);
DECLARE @MyField_ID varchar(250);
DECLARE @MyField_NewPos int

BEGIN 
SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR 
SELECT      WATCHLIST_USER
        ,   WATCHLIST_ID
FROM    inserted
WHERE inserted.WATCHLIST_POSITION is null

OPEN @MyCursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor
INTO @MyField_USER,  @MyField_ID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN 
    set @MyField_NewPos = (SELECT MAX(WATCHLIST_POSITION) + 1 FROM TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE WHERE WATCHLIST_USER = @MyField_USER)
    print @MyField_NewPos

    update TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE 
        SET WATCHLIST_POSITION = ISNULL(@MyField_NewPos,0)
        WHERE       WATCHLIST_USER = @MyField_USER 
            AND     WATCHLIST_ID = @MyField_ID
            AND     WATCHLIST_POSITION IS NULL 

        Print @MyField_USER 
        Print @MyField_ID
        FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor
        INTO @MyField_USER,  @MyField_ID
END;


END;
CLOSE @MyCursor
```

Comment: Why?? You don't need a *cursor* to calculate incrementing values per user. This will end up N times slower than the equivalent single update, where N the number of rows. Why don't you use `ROW_POSITION()`? And add `MAX()` as well if you want to start from the previous maximum

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE_ADD_POSITION ON TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE  AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN 
    WITH DataSource AS
    (
        SELECT DS.WATCHLIST_USER
              ,COUNT(*) - 1 AS WATCHLIST_POSITION
        FROM TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE DS
        INNER JOIN inserted I
            ON DS.WATCHLIST_USER = I.WATCHLIST_USER
        WHERE inserted.WATCHLIST_POSITION is null
        GROUP BY DS.WATCHLIST_USER
    )
    UPDATE TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE
    SET WATCHLIST_POSITION = DS.[WATCHLIST_POSITION]
    FROM TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE DS
    INNER JOIN DataSource I
        ON DS.WATCHLIST_USER = I.WATCHLIST_USER;
END
```

Comment: Hi gotqn

i get the following errors:
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE_ADD_POSITION, Line 6
Invalid column name 'rowid'.

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE_ADD_POSITION, Line 6
The multi-part identifier "inserted.rowid" could not be bound.

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE_ADD_POSITION, Line 6
The multi-part identifier "inserted.WATCHLIST_POSITION" could not be bound.

Comment: @SimonBruun Could you try again?

Comment: rowid is not a permanent column in the TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE table.

I think rowid is a build-in "column" in mySQL. 

TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE definition:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE](
 [WATCHLIST_USER] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
 [WATCHLIST_ID] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
 [WATCHLIST_DATA] [varchar](4000) NOT NULL,
 [WATCHLIST_POSITION] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [WATCHLIST_USER] ASC,
 [WATCHLIST_ID] ASC
)

Comment: @SimonBruun Do you have `ID`/ primary key column(s) on which we can perform the join?

Comment: No, not as it is atm :( .. I think your first suggestion got us in a good direction: 
CREATE TRIGGER TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE_ADD_POSITION ON TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN 
    UPDATE TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE 
    SET WATCHLIST_POSITION = (SELECT COUNT(*) - 1 FROM TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE WHERE WATCHLIST_USER = inserted.WATCHLIST_USER) 
    WHERE rowid = inserted.rowid and inserted.WATCHLIST_POSITION is null
END

Comment: @SimonBruun what is this trigger supposed to do? You may not even need a trigger, or need a very simple one, if you can use a ranking function. Or you may need a SEQUENCE to generate increasing numbers instead of using an IDENTITY

Comment: @SimonBruun Can't we join using the name?

Comment: Wow.. the help on this site, is overwhelming !
thanks for all your effort to make this work for me.

Please give me some time to take it all in..

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are looking for a ranking function, or even a simple `COUNT(*)` per user? MySQL is rather poor in [analytic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/analytic-functions-transact-sql), [ranking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql) or windowing functions so tricks like quirky updates or triggers are used to emulate them.

In SQL Server, you could return the number of records that match a single user in each row with `COUNT()` applied over the records that match a single user :

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY WATCHLIST_USER)
FROM TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE
```

No need for a trigger. You can use any aggregate with an OVER() clause.

If you want the *rank* according to some order, you can use one of the ranking functions like `ROW_NUMBER()` or `RANK(). If you want to calculate a row position per user based, eg on creation date you could write :

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER(*) OVER (PARTITION BY WATCHLIST_USER ORDER BY CreationDate)
FROM TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE
```

If you have an incrementing ID you could use it to generate a `row position` per user

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER(*) OVER (PARTITION BY WATCHLIST_USER ORDER BY ID)
FROM TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE
```

Most of the time, you *don't* need to store the row position. It's simple enough to add a ranking function  to a query.

If you do need to store such a row position in a table, you could use a simple multi-row trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE_ADD_POSITION 
ON TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    update TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE 
    set WATCHLIST_POSITION =ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WATCHLIST_USER ORDER BY ID)
    FROM inserted 
    INNER JOIN TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE on inserted.ID=TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE.ID
```

Or

```
update TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE 
set WATCHLIST_POSITION =ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WATCHLIST_USER ORDER BY ID)
FROM inserted 
INNER JOIN TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE 
    ON inserted.WATCHLIST_USER =TF_WATCHLIST_PERSISTENCE.WATCHLIST_USER
```

If you want to insert new entries for an existing user and recalculate all positions